Django ModelForm doesn't update instance but fails with IntegrityError
I'm having some really weird issue with a ModelForm. Instead of saving the instance, it attempts to create the instance with the same primary key.
class Upload(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_foundry_upload_name, null=False, blank=False)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)

    foundry = models.ForeignKey(Foundry, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    family = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    family_select = models.ForeignKey(Family, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    style = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    style_select = models.ForeignKey(Style, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    processed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField("Created", auto_now_add=True)

    # edit: this was omitted in the original question, because I thought it irrelevant
    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.filename = self.file.name
        super().save(commit)


class UploadProcessForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        fields = (
            "filename",
            "family",
            "family_select",
            "style",
            "style_select",
        )


def upload_process_row(request, foundry, id):
    
    i = get_object_or_404(Upload, id=id, foundry=foundry)
    upload_form = UploadProcessForm(instance=i)

    if request.method == "POST":
        upload_form = UploadProcessForm(request.POST, instance=i)
        if upload_form.is_valid():
            upload_form.save()
    
    return render(request, "foundry/upload_process.row.html", {
        "f": upload_form
    })


django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "foundry_upload_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.

I'm certain this is some super trivial mistake, but I just cannot spot where I'm going wrong; imo this looks exactly like the textbook example. The upload_form.save() always attempts to create a database entry, and with the instance's primary key. I'd just want to update the existing instance (that's the whole point of a ModelForm, no?).
I've wiped the database table and migrations and recreated them fresh, just to be sure.
Edit: I've added the save overwrite in Upload that I originally omitted as irrelevant. A closer look at the stacktrace (:facepalm:) pointed out that it is that save() call where the pk error originates from. However, now that I know where the error is triggered, I still don't understand why? Shouldn't that simply save with the same pk again?

That is strange. Does it work if you do:
i = get_object_or_404(Upload, id=id)
whithout foundry. Because It seems to create a new foundry with the same primary key ...
"foundry_upload_pkey" DETAIL: Key (id)=(1) already exists
I don't know if this is the reason of the problem, anyway each upload instance have a unique id, so it's not usefull to add a filter.. don't you think ?

Okay, it starts making a bit more sense now; it's not the ModelForm per se, but the model's save method where the issue comes from. I didn't check the stacktrace closely enough to spot this earlier!

The model's save method used an wrong/outdated signature. It should be:
def save(self, **kwargs):
        self.filename = self.file.name
        super().save(**kwargs)

The original triggered the the commit when it should not, thus resulting in duplicate primary keys.

Due to lack of context I couldn't provide the solid solution but there are few things you can try for dubugging the issue.
Try clearing the cache if there’s any caching or transaction issues, Django might not recognize the instance. Ensure that migrations are fully applied, and consider clearing the session and restarting the development server.
Add a debugging statement before the save() call to confirm that upload_form.instance is indeed the same object and not a new one:
print(upload_form.instance.id)

You can explicitly set primary key as temporary workaround
if upload_form.is_valid():
obj = upload_form.save(commit=False)
obj.id = i.id  # explicitly set the id to the existing instance's id (not very good practice)
obj.save()

